# How to implement multitenant MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant

I am looking to implement a MongoDB system that has 3 major collections (People, Surveys, Responses) and a few minor collections (lookups etc).  However, the system will be multi-tenant, so I will need a set of collections for each tenant.  My question is should I have separate DBs for each tenant, or should I have a single db.  With a single db, should I name my collections as follows: tenantname_people, tenantname_surveys etc, or is there a better way to structure/name my collections?  I like the single db approach, because then I can have a tenant collection, with details of each tenant and their users etc, which will be helpful for support.  I will have quite a few indexes, and I have one eye on the 24k limit on namespaces.  24k seems high, but these things can haunt you.

Any helpful comments would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the recommended approach towards multi-tenant databases in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748825/what-is-the-recommended-approach-towards-multi-tenant-databases-in-mongodb)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

definitely a separate DB is the appropiate way, so you can easily apply replication and make redundant versions of a tenant. a single DB will bite you when you want to scale out the service

what you need to do is have a tenant ID and a single user db which is a management db and you can have there the information for users and tenants.

Comment: Not definitely — each database gets pre-allocated file space and your databases will grow very quickly (see here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space). Using server-grade hardware with replication this cost quickly adds up. Personally I think it's better to go for the single DB and keep an eye on the namespace limits (serverdensity.com can do this for you).

Comment: consider using Collections (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Collections) instead of completely separate databases

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend having separate DB per tenant. This can help you with sharding as well. You can increase the namespace limit if you want to using the --nssize argument.

Comment: `--nssize` docs are here (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections). Important to note that the 24k limit is _per db_. If you have a separate DB per tenant then you'll sidestep this requirement.