# Is there a limit on the number of schemas in a MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant

Looking into multi-tenant architecture and this is something I am new to. One of the methodologies I came across was having a different schema in a database for each customer.

Is there a limit to the number of schemas in a MongoDB database?

What are some of the pros and cons of having a schema per customer in a shared tenant architecture?

Comment: Define "schema" in the context of MongoDB. Do you mean "databases"? Or "collections" ? Or something else?

Comment: Also pros and cons compared to what? Dedicated MongoDB instance per customer? A different non-MongoDB database product?

Comment: Related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748825/what-is-the-recommended-approach-towards-multi-tenant-databases-in-mongodb?rq=1