# One customer per Collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant

I am working on an enterprise level multi tenancy system and we are discussing how to partition our MongoDB and I'm reading up on how to do this but I have a few questions if there is an expert here that can help me.
Just to underline: I *have* read up on this and tried to search for info, but it fails to answer my question (or my google-fu fails me completely).

Question 1:
One customer per collection.

This scenario is something that people talk about avoiding and I'm not really satisfied with the answer way.
I understand that there is a namespace limit and there is a problem if you have more than 100 collections, but what if you build around that?

My idea is to limit the maximum of collections in a database to X (50? 80? 30? some cool number) and to use several instances of the database but not one per customer. This is due to economy, I want to press the cost per tenant and thus putting several tenants in one database and placing each tenant in a collection to create a good scaling of the collections.
As far as I understand when I read the documentation about Mongo DB my scenario above would be OK as long as I keep a watchful eye on how many collections I have in each database. This will give me a good spread of info over the different collections, thus utilizing MongoDBs scaling possibilities while still keeping the cost resonable.
The connectionstring to different databases would not be a huge issue, I can handle that simply enough.

I would find the above scenario easier than keeping the customers seperated with customer_id and spreading the info into different collection based on something else.

Is my reasoning still incorrect? If yes - why? Where is my logic failing me?

Question 2:
(This question is only valid if the answer to question 1 is "no no, you are right" :) )
If I now use the above scenario and I have multiple customers that are a chain of stores for instance. Let's say IKEA (they have a lot of stores) and you have a general manager some place that needs information from all of the IKEA tenants I would need to go into several collections to find the overall statistic info, is this a problem?
I already thought about placing certain customers in one specific database for them (like IKEA or other chains) meaning that if they are less than 100 stores then I "only" need to view one database, but I need to fetch information from several different collections, is this a problem?

I know there are several references to similar questions, like:

[What is the recommended approach towards multi-tenant databases in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748825/what-is-the-recommended-approach-towards-multi-tenant-databases-in-mongodb)

https://web.archive.org/web/20140812091703/http://support.mongohq.com/use-cases/multi-tenant.html

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-multi-tenant-patterns-for-building-saas-applications-on-sql-database/

but I feel that they lack the answer to this form of question.

I hope you understand the difference in my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find any answer to it? Are you going with collection per tenant approach?

Comment: I am looking at MongoDB multi-tenancy and the only way of doing multi-tenancy on MondoDB that is secure is to do One Collection per Tenant. This would allow creating User(s) that have access to only their content and have Application level RBAC for Tenant content.